# Show loader on Vue 3 async axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios

this is my first Vue 3 project...

I'm trying to show a loader during Axios async request.
This is my component

```
<script setup>
  import { defineProps, onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios'
  const props = defineProps({
    publicKey: String
  })

  const tokens = ref([]);

  const loader = computed(() => {
    return tokens.value.length > 0
  })

  onMounted(async () => {
      console.log(loader);
      const url = `https://example.com/${props.publicKey}/nfts/metadata`
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      tokens.value = res.data;
      console.log(loader);
    });

</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="loader">
    <div class='anim-circle'></div>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
  {{tokens}}
  </div>
</template>
```

It's doesn't work, I try in several ways without success...

I edit the script in this way

```
<script setup>
import {
  defineProps,
  onMounted,
  reactive,
  computed
} from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios'
const props = defineProps({
  publicKey: String
})

let tokens = reactive([]);

const loaded = computed(() => {return !(tokens?.length > 0)})

onMounted(async () => {
  const url = `https://api.example.io/solana/account/${props.publicKey}/nfts/metadata`
  const res = await axios.get(url);
  tokens.push(...res.data);
});
</script>

<template>
<div v-if="loaded.value">
  <div class="row">

    <div v-for="token in tokens.nfts" v-bind:key="token.id" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 mb-4 pb-2">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Token', params: { id: token.id }}">
      <div class="nft-collection nft-col-primary p-3 bg-white rounded-md">
        <img :src="token.image" class="img-fluid rounded-md shadow mb-2">

        <div class="content mt-3 p-2 rounded-md" style="background-color: white">
          <a class="title text-light h3" href="">
            {{token.name}}
            {{token.description}}
          </a>
          <ul class="pt-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li>
              <!-- <span v-for="skill in buddha.metadata" v-bind:key="skill" class="badge bg-soft">{{skill}}</span> -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <div class="row loading">
  <div class='anim-circle'></div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Token is now reactive and I push the result of the axios call into the array.
I change to "loaded" and if is loaded then show my results, if is not loaded show the loader.

The error in console is

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
    at eval (TokenList.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[1]:24)
```

**Another tentative refactoring**

```
<script setup>
import {
  defineProps,
  onMounted,
  ref,
  computed
} from 'vue';

import axios from 'axios'
const props = defineProps({
  publicKey: String
})

const tokens = ref([])
const loadingState = ref(null)
const showToken = computed(() => loadingState.value === 'success' )

// Fetch Data Feature
const fetchAllTokens = () => {
  console.log(showToken.value);
  loadingState.value = 'loading'
  const url = `https://api.unlocktech.io/solana/account/${props.publicKey}/nfts/metadata`
  return axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      loadingState.value = 'success'
      tokens.value = response.data.nfts
      console.log(tokens.value);
      console.log(showToken.value);
    })

}

onMounted(
  fetchAllTokens()
);
</script>

<template>
<div v-if="showToken.value">
  <div class="row">

    <div v-for="token in tokens.value" v-bind:key="token.id" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 mb-4 pb-2">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Token', params: { id: token.id }}">
      <div class="nft-collection nft-col-primary p-3 bg-white rounded-md">
        <img :src="token.image" class="img-fluid rounded-md shadow mb-2">

        <div class="content mt-3 p-2 rounded-md" style="background-color: white">
          <a class="title text-light h3" href="">
            {{token.name}}
            {{token.description}}
          </a>
          <ul class="pt-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li>
              <!-- <span v-for="skill in buddha.metadata" v-bind:key="skill" class="badge bg-soft">{{skill}}</span> -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <div class="row loading">
  <div class='anim-circle'></div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

In the console I have "`false`" and then "`true`" but the conditional loading doesn't work

Comment: What does exactly not work? What is logged data? Are there errors?

Comment: I guess `loader` default value is set to `false`. It seems `tokens.value.length` is `undefined` and so the statement will return  `false`. So it doesn't show at first. You should set it to `true` by default and change it when response is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `reactive` rather than `ref` for object(array)

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html

so this is the new code:

```
<script setup>
  import { defineProps, onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios'
  const props = defineProps({
    publicKey: String
  })

  const tokens = reactive([]);

  const loader = computed(() => {
    return tokens?.length > 0
  })

  onMounted(async () => {
      console.log(loader);
      const url = `https://example.com/${props.publicKey}/nfts/metadata`
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      tokens = res.data;
      console.log(loader);
    });

</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="loader">
    <div class='anim-circle'></div>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
  {{tokens}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "loader" should be

`const loader = computed(() => {return !(tokens?.length > 0)})`

Because you want to show the loader, if there are no items in the tokens array.
Additionally `tokens` is a `const` so you can't reassign it. You should use `tokens.push(...res.data)` instead.

Furthermore as @ImagiNiha showed, you should use `reactive` instead of `ref`.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried but I receive an error... :-(
With tokens.push(...res.data) i cannot list my tokens...

Comment: @Roberto Pezzali
Could you provide the error you are receiving?

Comment: I edited adding the new code refactored following your advice.

Comment: Okay, i can't reproduce the exact same error, but i have some Suggestions.

I think the error is a result of this. You try to access `tokens.nfts` in the `v-for`. Since tokens is an array it does not have this property. So does the axios request provide an array of tokens or just 1 ? If it is just 1 object try 'tokens.push(res.data)` and adjust the `v-for`

Also you can't use `loaded.value`, just use `loaded` in the template. 
Secondly since you switched your v-if ordering  the correct `loaded` is now `const loaded = computed(() => {return tokens?.length > 0))`

Comment: Ok I try to push the array and not the single value. I also try another way, using a loading value changed into the axios call but it doesn’t works

Comment: Okay, so now there is still the issue with `showToken.value`. In the Template/Html part the refs are automatically unwraped, so `v-if=showToken`and `v-for=token in tokens`should be correct .  https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping

Does `console.log(tokens.value);` show something? 
Furthermore could you provide an example of the structure of the `response.data`.

Comment: I fix it! Removing the value